# MSP430 I2C Problem During Start Condition

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, i2c, msp430

I'm working with an MSP430F249T and I have some issues using I2C interface.
After the first I2C initializzation I try to do a write but it fails after the start condition.
The problem is when I check the UCTXSTT flag, where it seems never ending the slave address transmition.
I tried to hook up an oscilloscope and I can see the start condition, but not the slave address be transmitted.

Below I share my code;

```
#pragma location = "APP_INTERNAL_SEG"
void i2c_msp_init(unsigned char DevAddr, USHORT ClkIdDivisor)
{
    //P5SEL |= 0x06;                            // I2C su USCI_B1: SDA sul pin 5.1 e SCL sul pin 5.2; l'I2C è disponibile sulla USCI_B0 e sulla USCI_B1
    UCB1CTL1 = UCSWRST;                      // si entra nella condizione di SW reset
    UCB1CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC;     // I2C Master in synchronous mode
    
    UCB1CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2;            // UCSSEL_2 per utilizzare SMCLK, UCSWRST per restare nella condizione di SW reset
    
    // lvMF
    //  UCB1BR0 = I2C_FREQ_100K;                  // fSCL = SMCLK/12 = ~100kHz
    //  UCB1BR1 = 0;
    UCB1BR0 = LOBYTE(ClkIdDivisor);
    UCB1BR1 = HIBYTE(ClkIdDivisor);
    
    UCB1I2CSA = DevAddr;                      // ad UCB1I2CSA assegna l'indirizzo del dispositivo con cui si deve comunicare
        
        P5SEL |= 0x06;                            // I2C su USCI_B1: SDA sul pin 5.1 e SCL sul pin 5.2; l'I2C è disponibile sulla USCI_B0 e sulla USCI_B1
    UCB1CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // si esce dall condizione di SW reset
    
    // lvMF
    // ATTENZIONE !!!
    // NON SI PUO' RICONFIGURARE IL TIMER-A PERCHE' USATO DALLO STACK KNX
    //  TACTL = TASSEL_2 + MC_2;                  // SMCLK, contmode
}
```

```
#pragma location = "APP_INTERNAL_SEG"
BOOL i2c_msp_start_tx(void)
{
    int count01;
    int count02;
    
       // while(UCB1STAT & UCBBUSY);
        
    UCB1CTL1 |= (UCTR | UCTXSTT);  // I2C TX start: si trasmette UCB1I2CSA

    count01 = 0;
    while(UCB1CTL1 & UCTXSTT)
    {
        // si aseptta la fine della tx
        count01++;
        if(count01 > COUNT_MAX)
            return FALSE;
    }
    
    count01 = 0;
    while(UCB1STAT & UCNACKIFG)             // se c'è nack sulla tx si fa repeated start (si invia un nuovo start)
    {
        count01++;
        if(count01 > COUNT_MAX)
            return FALSE;
        
        UCB1CTL1 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;         // I2C TX start
        
        count02 = 0;
        while(UCB1CTL1 & UCTXSTT)         // si aseptta la fine della tx
        {
            count02++;
            if(count02 > COUNT_MAX)
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
    
    return TRUE;
}
```

When I try the transmittion again (I re-init every time the I2C before one transmittion) the SDA line gets stuck low and the BUSY flag remains set to 1.

Comment: No idea of the bit pattern values, but you mix logical using OR with using arithmetic ADD in this code snippet... The latter may have consequences that the former does not...

Comment: I checked the registers and seem to be fine. I tried to use only OR statement but still not working

Answer (score 0):

The MSP430 I²C peripheral stalls the bus after the start bit until you provide it with the first data byte. So you need to write UCB1TXBUF before checking UCTXSTT.

Here is the code I use for writing to the I²C bus (however on UCB0, you'd have to change that):

```c
i2c_result_t i2c_write(uint8_t addr, size_t len, uint8_t *data) {
    if (len == 0) {
        return I2C_LEN_INVALID;
    }

    // Ensure STOP condition of the previous transmission has been sent
    while (UCB0CTLW0 & UCTXSTP)
        ;

    UCB0IFG &= ~UCTXIFG0;

    UCB0I2CSA = addr;
    // Direction: transmit
    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTR;

    // Generate START and transmit adress and R/W bit
    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;

    // Wait until eUSCI_B is ready for the first data byte
    while (!(UCB0IFG & UCTXIFG0))
        ;

    // eUSCI_B stalls the bus and won't update UCTXSTT and UCNACKIFG until the first data byte is available
    UCB0TXBUF = data[0];

    // Wait until address has been sent before checking UCNACKIFG
    while (UCB0CTLW0 & UCTXSTT)
        ;

    // React with STOP if no slave ACK'ed the address
    if (UCB0IFG & UCNACKIFG) {
        UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;
        return I2C_ADDR_NACK;
    }

    // Skip the first byte which has already been sent
    for (size_t i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        // UCTXIFG0 is set when UCB0TXBUF is ready for the next data byte
        while (!(UCB0IFG & UCTXIFG0))
            ;

        // Writing to UCB0TXBUF automatically clears UCTXIFG0
        UCB0TXBUF = data[i];
    }

    // Wait until transmission of the last byte has begun before setting UCTXSTP
    while (!(UCB0IFG & UCTXIFG0))
        ;

    // Generate STOP
    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;

    return I2C_OK;
}
```